# Why do I sometimes have to provide complete path of a dataset in Pandas to read it while other times it works by only providing the dataset filename?

Tags: python, pandas, macos, spyder

I have no idea why this happens. Sometimes it reads the dataset by just providing the filename (dataset belonging to the same directory as the code) while other times it requires complete path of the file. I am using Spyder IDE and Pandas to read the file. My OS is macOS Mojave.

Comment: it really depends where you run the code from and where the dataset actually lives, which seems like it changes in your situation

Comment: My dataset is in the same directory as my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the current working directory set in spyder using:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Once this is known, you know whether your file is in the same path. If not, you can do two things:

1. Using Tools > Preferences > Current working directory you can change the path to what you want
2. or programatically do the same thing as follows:

`os.chdir('/Users/theroy/mlp')`

Comment: OMG this worked! Thanks. Even though my python file was in the directory of the dataset, the current working directory was somewhere else. Could you please help me understand why and/or how this happened?